# Import object in React not defined

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

In React:

**wording.js**

```
export  const wording = {
  id1: 'record',
  id2: 'play'
};
```

**test.js**

```
import { wording } from "...";

function Test(props) {

  const onCellClicked = (e) => {
    console.log("Hello", wording.id1);
    if(wording.id1 ) {
      ...
    }
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={onCellClicked} >Press me</button>
  )

}
```

When I am calling  and pressing the button, `console.log` responds correctly (getting `record`). However, by using Chrome Dev Tools and putting a break-point on `if`, `wording` is not defined!! Any logical explanation on that?

[image]

Comment: Please add a screen shot of how you are debugging it, where exactly is your break point, where you hover `wording` and all possible information.

Comment: My mate makes the same this morning. He forgot add .js as file extension. Hope it solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  putting a break-point on if, `wording` is not defined ...

Wich `wording` ? In your file, you have 2 places where you use `wording`.

In the react file, there is 2 places with the certain variable

- The place where you import it
- The place where you reference it (use it)

If you hover on the place where you use it, you will see the variable value

e.g.

[image]

But if you hover where you import it, it will be undefined

[image]

That happens because the variable of the import is out of scope and you certain won't be able to see it's value.

Comment: actually, his screenshot shows that the component is undefined when being used also

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper if you step to the next line, does it continues undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. Sometimes React compiled it, sometimes it didn't. This seems to be proper syntax so I can't tell you why this happens but I can tell you what I did to fix it. I just had to restructure my files a little bit. So for yours, you would change:

wording.js

```
export default {
  id1: 'record',
  id2: 'play'
};
```

test.js

```
import wording from "...";

function Test(props) {

  const onCellClicked = (e) => {
    console.log("Hello", wording.id1);
    if(wording.id1 ) {
      ...
```